# Need to upgrade from a shared server

Tags: magento-1.9, hosting

I need your advice on the next step up from shared servers to manage our **large catalogue of products** on our `magento 1.9` site.

We currently at the moment don't warrant spending the money just yet on a dedicated managed server so I have been looking in to VPS & Cloud servers.

We have a catalogue of around **1500 products**, but currently cannot add anymore onto our server as the quota is full.

Would a **VPS** server be ok? The one I have been looking at has a spec of:

> 2 vCores Intel Xeon Processors
>
> RAM 4GB
>
> Storage 120GB
>
> Traffic Unlimited
>
> Data Centre: United Kingdom
>
> OS: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Is this a good stable package to handle our catalogue and site?

Comment: It's hard to say without more info then just # of products.  Lots of factors determine hardware needs.  For your situation, I would recommend something that can scale automatically, like AWS Elastic Beanstalk https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the best performance of a Magento store depends on a large number of things. But one thing is most important to focus i.e. running Magento on the shared hosting server which (to be very honest) is a terrible idea! May be, you'll be able to get it running, but it's doubtful to stay the way because when you start getting the traffic or increase the number of components to your Magento, the store will be Rest In Peace.

It's a good news that you are thinking to switch your Magento store from a shared server to VPS server. You don't need to go with a cloud/dedicated server, VPS servers are significantly cheaper than cloud servers, and they can also be configured with ease to run a Magento store well as long as you do not see any substantial traffic spike.

The numbers you have mentioned i.e. Intel Xeon Processors (2 cores), 4GB RAM, 120GB SSD, is good enough to handle your requests. You need to make sure that you have optimized your Magento store properly and have implemented important cache mechanisms. With this right VPS hosting package and implementation of real cache, you can expect to achieve your desired goal.